# Какая логика должна быть у уведомлений на сайте?

Tags: php, база-данных, уведомления

Назрел вопрос, как реализовать систему уведомлений на сайте.
Как известно, уведомления могут быть трех типов:

1) Личные - сообщения, лайки, история посещений и т.п.
2) Глобальные - например я как админ выложил новость на сайте.
3) Локальные - например группе людей, подписчикам пользователя о его новом твите.

Вопрос, при реализации системы уведомлений, так и нужно их разделять на эти типы?

С первым все понятно, с первым типом мы просто создаем таблицу
notific

```
id|user_id|text|read
```

Со вторым возникает вопрос. Допустим я выложил новость как админ, и чтобы она была отмечена как прочитана пользователем приходит на ум только создать таблицу
read_news

```
id|news_id|user_id
```

Но мне кажется это не правильным вариантом, так как каждая новость тянет за собой количество записей помноженное на число пользователей.

С третьим вообще мало себе представляю, как каждый раз оповещать группу пользователей об изменении другого пользователя не создав при этом туеву кучу записей в бд.

Вопрос вот в чем, как вообще правильно реализовывается логика уведомлений на сайте? Правильно ли я мыслю? Как уменьшить кол-во записей в бд до минимума. Если есть какой-то мануал или уже существующий вопрос который я не нашел, прошу направить. Заранее премного благодарен, друзья.

Comment: Чтобы понять как данные лучше хранить, подумайте как вы будете их использовать. Если данные не нужно часто использовать на чтение, то можно сделать подобие логов в файлах. Ещё можно записать в одну строку в базе данных id новости| перечисление id всех пользователей. Все зависит от количества пользователей и количества новостей.